# TSConfig - Output ".js" File Generated Relative to each ".ts" file

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a non-standard application with the following file structure

```
project
├── tsconfig.json
├── app_1
│   ├── ts
│   └── js
|
└── app_2
    ├── ts
    └── js
```

I would like for files inside of the `ts` folder to be compiled and placed in its corresponding app's `js` folder (eg. compiled files for `.ts` files found in `app_1/ts` should be placed in `app_1/js`).

Currently, I'm using VSCode to compile my files and place them in their corresponding folders. However, I dont know how to structure my TSConfig file to allow me to do what I described. Can anybody help me with this. I've been trying to use the `outDir` property, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Make **two** tsconfigs, one for each app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to create 2 different tsconfig files (one in `app_1` and another one in `app_2`) and specify the appropriate `outDir` option for each.

Note that you can keep a root tsconfig file and have the 2 others inherit from the root using [`extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends). If both apps share the same config, it avoids duplicating all the TS config.

Comment: Did not think of that. Thank you, it works! Now another question. What if inside of `ts` I have lets say 3 subfolders for different functions and utilities (each one a `.ts` file), and I want each file to be compiled in the `js` folder, but with the corresponding subdirectories (eg. The file `app_1/ts/utils/function1.ts` would be compiled into app_1/`js/utils/function1.js`). Would that be possible?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the default behavior...

Comment: Currently my tsconfig.json is just this: 

`
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "js"
    }
`

Do I need to add anything else to make it work like I described? Because currently its just placing the file inside of the `js` directory.

Comment: You should not need anything else, if you have a file in `ts/subfolder/file.ts`, it should be transpiled in `js/subfolder/file.js`

Comment: There we go, the solution was to set the `rootDir` property to the `ts` directory. Now its working as intended. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, I forgot about that! I'm glad you could make it work